# How to create an Android app whose only purpose is to launch another app?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

While customizing my phone I'm trying to make an app that's just the Google Weather app, with a custom icon. I just want it to work exactly like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delta8studio.weather) app on the Play Store.

With every single code I find on the internet there's always the app-switching animation that I can't get rid of. I have tried to use `overridePendingTransition(0, 0)` in the code and `<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>` in the theme, but nothing changed. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error I've managed to get it working properly. I just needed to set the theme of the app like this:

```xml
...
<application
...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
...
```

and after doing so, I needed to have my MainActivity to be a normal `Activity` and not an `AppCompatActivity`, like this:

```
class MainActivity : Activity()
```

and eventually just start the desired activity in the `onResume` method:

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        startActivity(
            Intent().setComponent(
                ComponentName(
                    "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",
                    "com.google.android.apps.search.weather.WeatherExportedActivity"
                )
            )
        )
        finish()
    }
```

Comment: Would you know how to add a default value in the weather searchBox (to search weather for a specific city for example) ?